# Incredibly slow run times on fast machine in R

Tags: r, performance, runtime

My R analysis on a fresh machine was running a bit slow. So I ran some benchmarkme tests to see what was up and found out I rank dead last:

```
> res = benchmark_std()
```

#### Programming benchmarks (5 tests):

```
3,500,000 Fibonacci numbers calculation (vector calc): 0.483 (sec).
Grand common divisors of 1,000,000 pairs (recursion): 0.61 (sec).
Creation of a 3500x3500 Hilbert matrix (matrix calc): 0.19 (sec).
Creation of a 3000x3000 Toeplitz matrix (loops): 1.07 (sec).
Escoufier's method on a 60x60 matrix (mixed): 0.657 (sec).
```

#### Matrix calculation benchmarks (5 tests):

```
Creation, transp., deformation of a 5000x5000 matrix: 0.483 (sec).
2500x2500 normal distributed random matrix ^1000: 0.61 (sec).
Sorting of 7,000,000 random values: 0.54 (sec).
2500x2500 cross-product matrix (b = a' * a): 7.3 (sec).
Linear regr. over a 3000x3000 matrix (c = a \ b'): 4.92 (sec).
```

#### Matrix function benchmarks (5 tests):

```
Cholesky decomposition of a 3000x3000 matrix: 4.06 (sec).
Determinant of a 2500x2500 random matrix: 1.46 (sec).
Eigenvalues of a 640x640 random matrix: 0.427 (sec).
FFT over 2,500,000 random values: 0.193 (sec).
Inverse of a 1600x1600 random matrix: 1.3 (sec).

> plot(res)
You are ranked 49 out of 82 machines.
Press return to get next plot 
You are ranked 83 out of 83 machines.
Press return to get next plot 
You are ranked 82 out of 82 machines.
```

[image]

My computer specs make me suspicious of these results:

```
> get_cpu()
$`vendor_id`
[1] "GenuineIntel"

$model_name
[1] "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz"

$no_of_cores
[1] 12

> get_ram()
17.2 GB

> get_sys_details()
$`sys_info`$`sysname`
[1] "Windows"

$`sys_info`$release
[1] ">= 8 x64"

$`sys_info`$machine
[1] "x86-64"

$r_version$version.string
[1] "R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)"
```

I am skeptical of malware as this is a fresh machine. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: I have the same processor, 16 GB of RAM on Win 10 - and my single core performance is similar (slightly worse in every single test) on R 3.4.2. compared to yours.

Comment: Install a multi-threaded BLAS -- as I recall, Prof Ripley's site has some prebuilt for Windows -- so that you get all your 12 cores working on matrix problems.  Consider installing Linux too :)  Just kidding, I have a similar CPU (i-8700k) and it is a screamer.

Comment: My machine is relatively fast (`"Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz"`). I also time last in the matrix operations. I suspect many people people who submitted their data use an optimized BLAS (this is what is benchmarked here).

Comment: Mmh, I don't think that's it. `plot.ben_results` checks if your R is linked to an optimized BLAS and compares to results from machines with the same setting. There is something else. Possibly matrix operations have become slower (to achieve better accuracy) since benchmarkme was published? There are a few related entries in the NEWS files.

Comment: I just installed [`R Open`](https://mran.microsoft.com/rro) - the difference during matrix operations is huge: `2500x2500 cross-product matrix (b = a' * a): 0.08 (sec)` `Linear regr. over a 3000x3000 matrix (c = a \ b'): 0.0667 (sec)` `Cholesky decomposition of a 3000x3000 matrix: 0.0533 (sec).`.

Comment: I'm last for all 3 tests.